# How to convert express/nodejs code from callback hell to promise

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, promise

Please. Help me. I really need it. I only have like 8hrs to rewrite my code 2500 line of codes or else I will fail my subject.

I use express, mysql, nodejs

This is a sample code of mine where I put a new product from the database.

This is my plain 'callback hell' code:

```
router.post('/inventory/product/add', authenticationMiddleware(), function(req, res, next) {
// Validate data
    req.assert('productslug', 'Product Slug is required').notEmpty()
    req.assert('productcat', 'Product Category is required').notEmpty()
    req.assert('productorigin', 'Product Inspiration is required').notEmpty()
    req.assert('productname', 'Product Name is required').notEmpty()
    req.assert('productprice', 'Product Price is required').notEmpty()
    req.assert('productdesc', 'Product Description is required').notEmpty()

    var errors = req.validationErrors()

    // No errors were found. Passed Validation!
    if (!errors) {

       var product = {
        productslug: req.sanitize('productslug').escape().trim(),
        productcat: req.sanitize('productcat').escape().trim(),
        productorigin: req.sanitize('productorigin').escape().trim(),
        productname: req.sanitize('productname').escape().trim(),
        productprice: req.sanitize('productprice').escape().trim(),
        productdesc: req.sanitize('productdesc').escape().trim()
    }

    const db = require('../db.js')
    let sql = `INSERT INTO inventory_tbl(product_slug, product_category, product_origin, product_name, product_price, product_cog, product_desc, total_stock) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);`

    db.query(sql, [product.productslug, product.productcat, product.productorigin, product.productname, product.productprice, 0, product.productdesc, 0], (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) {
            req.flash('error', error)

            // render to views/inventory/product/add.ejs
            res.render('admin/inventory/product/add', {
                title: 'Perry in Disguise | Add Product',
                productslug: product.productslug,
                productcat: product.productcat,
                productorigin: product.productorigin,
                productname: product.productname,
                productprice: product.productprice,
                productdesc: product.productdesc
            })
        } else {
            req.flash('success', 'Data added successfully!')

            res.render('admin/inventory/product/add', {
                title: 'Perry in Disguise | Add Product',
                productslug: product.productslug,
                productcat: product.productcat,
                productorigin: product.productorigin,
                productname: product.productname,
                productprice: product.productprice,
                productdesc: product.productdesc
            })
        }
    })
} else {
    // Display errors to the user
    var error_msg = ''
    errors.forEach(function(error) {
        error_msg += error.msg + '<br>'
    })
    req.flash('error', error_msg)

    // Using req.body.name
    // because req.param('name') is depreciated
    res.render('admin/inventory/product/add', {
        title: 'Perry in Disguise | Add Product',
        productslug: req.body.productslug,
        productcat: req.body.productcat,
        productorigin: req.body.productorigin,
        productname: req.body.productname,
        productprice: req.body.productprice,
        productdesc: req.body.productdesc
    })
   }
})
```

Here is the code I use to add product. I need to convert it to promise code. It is so hard understand promise. I searched and searched for reference, this is I think the simplest example. Can someone help me to convert my code to this kind of code? This is the link:

https://jeremysu0131.github.io/Node-js-MySQL-with-Promise-%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A/

Comment: You could try using `util.promisify` to turn any node.js style callback into a version that uses a promise. So it'll be something like: `const query = promisify( db.query ); query( ... ).then(( results, fields ) => { ... }).catch( error => { ... });` But your code only contains one callback. So the promisified version will have the same amount of indentation as the original so this won't save you from 1-level deep 'callback-hell'.

Comment: there's no callback hell there at all - I see a single nested callback - if you can't deal with that, then you'll really struggle if you ever do end up with callback hell

Comment: *Can someone help me to convert my code to this kind of code?* Are you asking users to do your job for free for a task you are be paid for, or at least could expect to be paid? Contrary to popular belief, SO isn't a freelance service.

Comment: what module is `db`?

Comment: I didn't want to ask anyone for help. I promise. It's for school. I didn't meant to ask a work from you guys, I'm just asking for one so that I can use it as basis. I'm so sorry. @estus 

db is just the mysql.createConnection

Here, it doesnt show the callback hell, my other router has. I just picked the easiest so that Im not to much bother for you guys. I just need it for basis.

Comment: @estus Because of people like you SO is considered kind of hostile to newbies. Also you will lie if you tell us that you haven't ever used SO for solving tasks you were paid for.

Comment: @Igniter Yes, downvoting a question or even answering a bad question without explaining what's wrong with it is much more helpful. Asking a specific question is one thing. 'Write the code for me' is another. I was asked about things I was paid for and I solved problems that people were paid for. Those were legit questions though.

Comment: @CherylBlossom Consider asking more specific question once you will have specific code problem with converting your code that shows your attempt. That's where SO community is usually helpful. Asking for help without a specific question isn't considered a good question on SO. You can start with using promise-based library for your DB instead of callback-based. All popular DB libs have their promise counterparts, e.g. `mysql` and `promise-mysql`.

Comment: @Shilly - there's two callbacks, one inside the other :p but you're right ... with promises, there's no benefit - though, with async/await there is

Comment: @estus that is the problem. Im clueless of promise. Im so sorry for inconvenience. Don't reply again please. I'm just gonna do what you said. Thank you so much and sorry.

Comment: @JaromandaX True, I forgot that the initial router.post() call is also a callback. But that callback is not written in node.js error first callback style, so I'd have to look up if util.promisify would help with that as well.

Comment: @CherylBlossom That's not callback hell, you just scratched the surface. Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/w8vd56re/ , i'm just so bored i just refactored it ... i guess you'll fail your subject tho :/

Comment: @darklightcode thanks. Sorry. My router for dashboard has 9 nested query. I just thought that if I gave the easiest, someone will help me. Thank you so much :)

Comment: And if you guys think Im getting paid for this, Im not. Because of the business name I guess, but on our univ, we are required to have actual client.

Comment: @darklightcode - I'm bored too and came up with similar - https://jsfiddle.net/mdn480a6/

Comment: @JaromandaX nice read ! i'm more of an array guy. Perhaps OP will learn about the `spread operator` and `destructuring`, but now, failing a subject is more important, let's not interrupt

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to use `Promise` class and pass a function to it, that function gets two parameters, first, one in `resolve` and the second one is `reject`. in the function body, we run our `callback-based` function and in callback we check, if there is any error, we call `reject` function and pass the `error`, and if is not any error we call `resolve` and pass the result.
so we create a `Promise`, now we need to use it. for that, we call `.then` on `insertresult` variable for successful and `.catch` on error.

```
router.post('/inventory/product/add', authenticationMiddleware(), function(req, res, next) {
// Validate data
    req.assert('productslug', 'Product Slug is required').notEmpty()
    req.assert('productcat', 'Product Category is required').notEmpty()
    req.assert('productorigin', 'Product Inspiration is required').notEmpty()
    req.assert('productname', 'Product Name is required').notEmpty()
    req.assert('productprice', 'Product Price is required').notEmpty()
    req.assert('productdesc', 'Product Description is required').notEmpty()

    var errors = req.validationErrors()

    // No errors were found. Passed Validation!
    if (!errors) {

       var product = {
        productslug: req.sanitize('productslug').escape().trim(),
        productcat: req.sanitize('productcat').escape().trim(),
        productorigin: req.sanitize('productorigin').escape().trim(),
        productname: req.sanitize('productname').escape().trim(),
        productprice: req.sanitize('productprice').escape().trim(),
        productdesc: req.sanitize('productdesc').escape().trim()
    }

    const db = require('../db.js')
    let sql = `INSERT INTO inventory_tbl(product_slug, product_category, product_origin, product_name, product_price, product_cog, product_desc, total_stock) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);`
    const insertResult = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.query(sql, [product.productslug, product.productcat, product.productorigin, product.productname, product.productprice, 0, product.productdesc, 0], (error, results, fields) => {
            if (error) reject(error)
            else resolve(results)
        }
    });
    insertResult.then(result => {
            req.flash('success', 'Data added successfully!')

            res.render('admin/inventory/product/add', {
                title: 'Perry in Disguise | Add Product',
                productslug: product.productslug,
                productcat: product.productcat,
                productorigin: product.productorigin,
                productname: product.productname,
                productprice: product.productprice,
                productdesc: product.productdesc
            })
    }).catch(error => {
            req.flash('error', error)

            // render to views/inventory/product/add.ejs
            res.render('admin/inventory/product/add', {
                title: 'Perry in Disguise | Add Product',
                productslug: product.productslug,
                productcat: product.productcat,
                productorigin: product.productorigin,
                productname: product.productname,
                productprice: product.productprice,
                productdesc: product.productdesc
            })
    });
} else {
    // Display errors to the user
    var error_msg = ''
    errors.forEach(function(error) {
        error_msg += error.msg + '<br>'
    })
    req.flash('error', error_msg)

    // Using req.body.name
    // because req.param('name') is depreciated
    res.render('admin/inventory/product/add', {
        title: 'Perry in Disguise | Add Product',
        productslug: req.body.productslug,
        productcat: req.body.productcat,
        productorigin: req.body.productorigin,
        productname: req.body.productname,
        productprice: req.body.productprice,
        productdesc: req.body.productdesc
    })
   }
})
```